# How to reset the position (position()) in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have one XML file in which i have repeating , they have their own ITEM_ID and NAME. As you can see in the example, we have 6 ITEM:

```
<ITEMS>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEM_ID>1234</ITEM_ID>
        <ITEM_NAME>TEST_ITEM_1</ITEM_NAME>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEM_ID>3216</ITEM_ID>
        <ITEM_NAME>TEST_ITEM_2</ITEM_NAME>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEM_ID>8956</ITEM_ID>
        <ITEM_NAME>TEST_ITEM_3</ITEM_NAME>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEM_ID>4562</ITEM_ID>
        <ITEM_NAME>TEST_ITEM_4</ITEM_NAME>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEM_ID>4562</ITEM_ID>
        <ITEM_NAME>TEST_ITEM_5</ITEM_NAME>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEM_ID>8569</ITEM_ID>
        <ITEM_NAME>TEST_ITEM_6</ITEM_NAME>
    </ITEM>
</ITEMS>
```

I would like the result like this:

```
<ARTICLES>
    <ARTICLE CODE="1">
        <ARTICLE_ID>1234</ARTICLE_ID>
        <ARTICLE_NAME>TEST_ARTICLE_1</ARTICLE_NAME>
    </ARTICLE>
    <ARTICLE CODE="2">
        <ARTICLE_ID>3216</ARTICLE_ID>
        <ARTICLE_NAME>TEST_ARTICLE_2</ARTICLE_NAME>
    </ARTICLE>
    <ARTICLE CODE="3">
        <ARTICLE_ID>8956</ARTICLE_ID>
        <ARTICLE_NAME>TEST_ARTICLE_3</ARTICLE_NAME>
    </ARTICLE>
    <ARTICLE CODE="4">
        <ARTICLE_ID>4562</ARTICLE_ID>
        <ARTICLE_NAME>TEST_ARTICLE_4</ARTICLE_NAME>
    </ARTICLE>
    <ARTICLE CODE="4">
        <ARTICLE_ID>4562</ARTICLE_ID>
        <ARTICLE_NAME>TEST_ARTICLE_5</ARTICLE_NAME>
    </ARTICLE>
    <ARTICLE CODE="5">
        <ARTICLE_ID>8569</ARTICLE_ID>
        <ARTICLE_NAME>TEST_ARTICLE_6</ARTICLE_NAME>
    </ARTICLE>
</ARTICLES>
```

Here, the attribute CODE should have the position of the ITEM but where ITEM_ID are same for example 4th and 5th then in that case in the result file the CODE should have the same value as you can see in the result file (CODE attribute). The next Node shouldnt have the actual position from the input xml but the increment number as "5" as you can see the last ARTICLE in the result XML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you accept a result of: 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6 ...?

Comment: Another question: I see that the input items are not sorted by ID; what if there are **non-adjacent** items with the same ID?

Comment: No,it should be 123445. My only requirement is when there are same item id then in result article node should have similar code value and next node should have the increment number not 6

Comment: Well, you will get that with the answer by Martin Honnen. Note however that the original order is not necessarily preserved - esp. if the identical items are not adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the numbering with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="by-id" match="ITEM" use="ITEM_ID"/>

<xsl:template match="ITEMS">
  <ARTICLES>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-id', ITEM_ID)[1])]"/>
  </ARTICLES>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('by-id', ITEM_ID)" mode="article">
    <xsl:with-param name="code" select="$pos"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM" mode="article">
  <xsl:param name="code"/>
  <ARTICLE CODE="{$code}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ARTICLE>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM_ID">
  <ARTICLE_ID>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ARTICLE_ID>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM_NAME">
  <ARTICLE_NAME>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ARTICLE_NAME>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You seem to also want to replace the word "ITEM" in each name by "ARTICLE", that could be done by a template called in the template for `ITEM_NAME`. Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="by-id" match="ITEM" use="ITEM_ID"/>

<xsl:template match="ITEMS">
  <ARTICLES>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-id', ITEM_ID)[1])]"/>
  </ARTICLES>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('by-id', ITEM_ID)" mode="article">
    <xsl:with-param name="code" select="$pos"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM" mode="article">
  <xsl:param name="code"/>
  <ARTICLE CODE="{$code}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ARTICLE>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM_ID">
  <ARTICLE_ID>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ARTICLE_ID>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM_NAME">
  <ARTICLE_NAME>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="to-be-replaced" select="'ITEM'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="'ARTICLE'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </ARTICLE_NAME>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="to-be-replaced"/>
  <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($input, $to-be-replaced))">
      <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input, $to-be-replaced)"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$replacement"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, $to-be-replaced)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="to-be-replaced" select="$to-be-replaced"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin, when I am using this code in my style sheet it is working but taking a while to execute. Is there anyother efficient way to do the same thing or other code which works faster?

Comment: The issue is I am using the code for a big file in which there are so many ITEMs, I cannot provide you that file, could you please check this scenario?

Comment: As the XSLT code already uses a key, I don't think there is much you could do to improve performance in general. You might want to ask a new question about performance, stating the exact name and version of the XSLT processor you use and the amount of time it takes. Perhaps then someone has an idea about improving performance. But of course you could also consider or test yourself whether a different XSLT processor gives a better performance. If you move to XSLT 2.0 then the template based replace you be replaced with a call to the XPath `replace` function, which might perform better.

Comment: Hi Martin, please accept my appology, your solution was working fine. Due to other reason the processing was slow. Thanks Man.